# Why doe the shell script does not accept first argument

Tags: bash, shell, bash-function

I am new to unix shell scripting. I am trying to execute sample function with arguments but the shell does not recognize the first argument as first but rather as second.

```
#!/bin/bash
func(){
    echo "func"
    if [ -z $1 ]
    then echo "$1 received"
    else echo "not received"
    fi
    }
func "hello"
```

gives output
    func
    not received

where it should have given

```
func
hello received
```

Comment: Are trying to test that an argument is given, or that the argument is a non-empty string?  If the latter, then using `test -n` is fine.  If the former, you ought to be checking the value of `$#`.  (What response do you want to `func ""`?)

Answer (score 6):

Your test should be:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]
```

instead of `if [ -z $1 ]`

- -n: variable is not empty
- -z: variable is empty

**NOTE** you best add the quotes around $1; else it will not work when you pass no argument.

Comment: Specifically, `[ -z $1 ]` when no arguments are passed becomes `[ -z ]` which is interpreted by `[`/`test` as `[ -n -z ]` which is always true.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this.  My preference is:

```
#!/bin/bash
func(){ echo ${1:-no argument} passed; }
func "hello"
func ""
func
```

In this example, the second call will write "no argument passed".  If you want to change the behavior, remove the colon after the `1` in the function definition.  You can certainly use `test -n "$1"` (`test` is the same as `[`, except that you do not need a terminating `]` argument) but it would be more appropriate to check the value of `$#`, which gives a count of the number of arguments passed to the function.

```
func() { 
    if test $# -lt 1; then
        echo no argument passed
    else
        echo at least one argument passed
    fi
}
```